# App store rejection - "no defined ‘loadingView’ or ‘contentView’ elements"

Tags: ios, react-native

Apple have rejected my React Native app for external beta testing because:

> when reviewed on iPad running iOS 11.2.5 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6
>   network….the app launches to a white screen and no content is loaded.

After some weeks of back and forth, they’ve admitted that it was not related to IPV6, and have given me some further info:

> The app’s initial React Native view controller loads with no defined
>   ‘loadingView’ or ‘contentView’ elements. It appears that there is code
>   in place for Javascript updating, but as stated, we’re not seeing any
>   attempt at the app to reach out - it appears likely something was
>   disconnected between the executable and associated bundle files
>   between your project and the submission.

I have not seen this issue when testing on my own devices or on the iOS Simulator.  Even when submitting the app to TestFlight for internal beta testers, and then installing on my iPhone via the TestFlight iOS app, it always works fine.  So, I'm baffled as to why Apple sees this and I don't, and I don't really know where to start with debugging it.

Comment: Not sure how much you've tried, but what happens when you load the Test Flight beta on your phone with all the internet connectivity turned off (Airplane mode) ?

Comment: @sam.  Yeah, worth a try, but it works fine for me in Airplane Mode.  Even it I delete the app, reinstall the app from TestFlight, then turn on Airplane Mode before first launch of the app, it works.  (There's no data in it, but the screens all work.)

Comment: Is the test flight version the same exact version/build your are submitting to the App Store? Because, I suppose Apple does a complete review on your first beta build. If you passed that review, then your app must have worked the first time.

Comment: Also, If you can possibly add me to the test flight, I could try to reproduce what apple was seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, @Sam, but I think I know what's been happening now.  See my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, case closed, I think.  And it was procedural issue rather than a technical one, down to my misunderstanding of Apple's process.

I only thought I'd ever submitted my builds for External Beta review.  I hadn't intended to submit it for *actual* inclusion in the App Store just yet.  But I think that's what I must have done, and that's the version that Apple have been referring to all along.  They haven't actually been looking at my subsequent builds, where the problem was fixed, as a part of this process.  That's because those builds *were* submitted as External Beta test builds, which is a different review process.

Apple clarified this to me by sending me screen shots of the TestFlight version of the app (all good) vs the App Store submission binary (blank screen).  And the penny dropped.